# Java Array Loop to Display different noCourse

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I already writing a coding to accept noSem and noCourse from users. Each semester there will be a different noCourse. My problem is, I only can display data if users enter the same value of noCourse. I want it to show different between the Semester.

Here some output : 
[I seems the loop is working, but the data is null because cant access the specific course between semester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HplSQ.png)

Here some of my coding :

```
class studentCourse {

int noCourse, noSem;

void course() {

    BufferedReader inData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {

        System.out.print("Enter no of semester : ");
        noSem = Integer.parseInt(inData.readLine());

        String[][] sbjName = new String[noSem][];
        String[][] courseCode = new String[noSem][];
        int[][] CHour = new int[noSem][];
        int[][] Marks = new int[noSem][];

        // Semester loop
        for(int i = 0; i < noSem; i++) {

            System.out.println("\n\tSemester" + (i + 1));
            System.out.print("Enter number of course : ");
            noCourse = Integer.parseInt(inData.readLine());

            sbjName[i] = new String[noCourse];
            courseCode[i] = new String[noCourse];
            CHour[i] = new int[noCourse];
            Marks[i] = new int[noCourse];

            // course details loop
            for(int u = 0; u < noCourse; u++) {

                System.out.print("Enter Course Code : ");
                courseCode[i][u] = inData.readLine();

                System.out.print("Enter Course Name : ");
                sbjName[i][u] = inData.readLine();

                System.out.print("Enter Credit Hour : ");
                CHour[i][u] = Integer.parseInt(inData.readLine());

                System.out.print("Enter Marks : ");
                Marks[i][u] = Integer.parseInt(inData.readLine());

                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
        for(int row = 0; row < noSem; row++) {

        System.out.println("\nResult Semester " + (row + 1));
        System.out.println("Course Code\t Course Name\t Credit Hour\t Marks\n");
        courseCode[row] = new String[noCourse];

            for(int col = 0; col < noCourse; col++) {

                // display course code
                System.out.print("Value row = " + row);
                System.out.print("Value of col = " + col);
                System.out.print(courseCode[row][col] + "\t");                      
                System.out.print("\n");


            }
            /*  

                // display subject name
                for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
                    for(int y = 0; y < sbjName[x].length; y++) {
                        System.out.print(sbjName[x][y] + "\t");

                    }

                } 

                // display credit hour
                for(int x = 0; x < CHour.length; x++) {
                    for(int y = 0; y < CHour[x].length; y++) {
                        System.out.print(CHour[x][y] + "\t");
                    }
                }

                // display marks
                for(int x = 0; x < Marks.length; x++) {
                    for(int y = 0; y < Marks[x].length; y++) {
                        System.out.print(Marks[x][y]);
                    }
                } */
            }
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Aobj) {
        System.out.println("Could not access the index!" );
    }

    catch (Exception Eobj) {}
}
}
```

Comment: problem aside, you should have named noCourse as CourseNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have re-initialized `courseCode` before displaying the results from it. Remove this line of code

   courseCode[row] = new String[noCourse];

before displaying your results and everything will work fine.

2. The variable noCourse might different for each of the semesters. This means using the variable to get your results is error prone. Instead, use the length of any of arrays, e.g. courseCode to fetch your result:

> ```
> for(int row = 0; row < courseCode.length; row++) {
>   System.out.println("\nResult Semester " + (row + 1));
>   System.out.println("Course Code\t Course Name\t Credit Hour\t Marks\n");    
>   for(int col = 0; col < courseCode[row].length; col++) {
>       System.out.print(courseCode[row][col] + "\t");
>       System.out.print(sbjName[row][col] + "\t");
>       System.out.print(CHour[row][col] + "\t");
>       System.out.print(Marks[row][col] + "\t");                      
>       System.out.print("\n");
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I already tried this before. It just display the output if user input same value for noCourse. I get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds I use that ..

Comment: I tested the code and it works fine after removing that line of code.  http://prntscr.com/cu6udy

Comment: Try to input different noCourse. Example , semester 1 noCourse = 2, Semester 2 noCourse = 3.

Comment: I have updated my answer.